# Correct handling of HTTP connection life-cycle in long running requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, asynchronous

I have a heavy I/O process that I initiate in using an endpoint. That endpoint should immidiately respond to the client that the process has been started.

The heavy I/O task could take up-to 30mins so what I'm wondering is that in what state does the connection between server and client leave after `res.json(...)`? Is the socket connection still open / half-open? Should I in this case destory the socket manually after `res.json(...)`? Is is Ok that the `heavyIO` task fails after 29mins and goes to the express error handler? And finally; is this pattern incorrect e.g., should I process I/O tasks totally differently?

Below is a minimal example:

```js
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

const asyncHandler = (handler) =>
  (req, res, next) => Promise.resolve(handler(req, res, next)).catch(next)
const heavyIO = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? resolve() : reject('FAILED'), 1000))

app.get('/start', asyncHandler(async (_req, res) => {
  // I want to be able to initiate the process and send back
  // confirmation that the process has been started. I want the
  // client to be able forget about this request.
  res.json('ok...started process')

  // Then we start to run the heavy IO process. Without the "await" this could
  // lead to unhandled promise rejection.

  // If this fails, the rejected promise will flow to express default
  // error handling which is I think "finalhandler" by default.
  // Because the headers as sent (res.headersSent === true) the error
  // handler will log the error and destroy the socket connection.

  // If this succeeds, the server will probably close the socket connection as well
  // internally.

  // Up until this point the socket has been open (or half-open?) so is this a problem?
  
  // Does it mean that the client has been "up-keeping" this socket connection
  // somehow or has/can it have been timed out before this succeeds or fails.
  await heavyIO()
  console.log(`FINISHED I/O at ${new Date().toISOString()}! Exiting handler...`)
}))

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: _"has/can it have been timed out before this succeeds or fails."_ The client could time out the connection. But I don't understand why you need a connection after `res.json('ok...started process')`. It could be closed after this line.

Comment: @jabaa that's true. If the I/O succeeds or fails, we shouldn't notify the client back using this connection, at least. How do I close the connection?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Why do you even keep the connection open? Why do you use the `asyncHandler` and `async`? Why do you `await` the function `heavyIO`? There is no communication between client and server after `res.json('ok...started process')`.

Comment: If you close the connection, the client will need to poll for status regularly. For a process that takes considerable time, keeping a connection open doing nothing for 30 minutes or more seems wasteful (to me). Pooling in regular intervals seems to be more adequate. An alternative would be to use web sockets to have an always-open communications channel between client and server, which allows the server to send progress updates. Given that web sockets are more complex and therefore might introduce issues of their own, I would go with polling.

Comment: @Tomalak Where do you see communication after `res.json('ok...started process')`? The status and header are sent. The response message is sent. What do you want to poll?

Comment: Polling also works well with the REST approach: **1)** `POST /jobs/new` (results in job ID) **2)** `GET /jobs/{id}/status` (results in progress info) **3)** `GET /jobs/{id}/result` (results in produced data).

Comment: @jabaa Huh? I started my argument with *"keeping a connection open seems wasteful"*. So obviously I would close it and use a separate endpoint to poll for progress.

Comment: @Tomalak What do you want to poll? Just close the connection. There is no result or status to poll.

Comment: @jabaa In a process that takes 30 minutes, there very likely is something to poll.

Comment: @Tomalak Okay, so you're interpreting more code into this question. I'm just talking about the provided code. The response is finished with `res.json` in the given code.

Comment: @jabaa I want to leverage the express error handler and logging middleware. My current code doesn't have the `await` so we forget the I/O process totally. But I needed to place extra `catch` blocks to `heavyIO` because I couldn't just bubble up the error to the express error handler. So in essence, I could make a cleaner code using this pattern and yeah that's the crux of my question that does this even make sense.

Comment: As you can see in my comments for me the whole question doesn't make sense. You don't send any results or status to the client. You don't send errors to the client. Handle the error inside `heavyIO` and close the connection after `res.json`

Comment: In my more complete code, the `heavyIO` sends updates of the long I/O process back to the request initiator using its another endpoint. I don't re-use/carry over the current response object.

Comment: @jabaa Yes. The reason the OP is asking is because they would *like* to keep the connection open so that the client can react when the job finally completes. If the client would not need to react, then *"how is the connection status in a long-running process"* would not be an issue at all. So I infer that there is progress (even as rudimentary as "done"/"not yet") and there is a need for keeping the client informed.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the client doesn't timeout? What is the client? AFAIK some browsers timeout after 4-5 minutes. You can't keep a connection open for 30 minutes. I don't know when operating systems or routers time out a connection but I assume it's less than 30 minutes.

Comment: @jabaa that's the problem, I cannot rely on the client to keep open the request. With load balancers in between, it becomes more difficult to tinker with the timeouts. I have the `await` just so I don't need to write all logging code and error handling in `heavyIO` and leverage the middlewares in express for those, but it has become apparent that this was a bad idea.

Comment: ...that's precisely why I suggested closing the connection and doing polling (i.e. letting the client send an Ajax request every N seconds).